# HttpServletRequest getting request parameters separated by # instead of?

Tags: spring-mvc, servlets, querystringparameter

I am trying to get the Query String Parameters in the controller from the following URL using javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest object:

http://example.com:8080/OAuthClient/oauth-callback#access_token=something&expires_in=1209600&username=abcuser

It does not work because it is separated by # instead of ?

Hence it works if I change the request to http://example.com:8080/OAuthClient/oauth-callback?access_token=something&expires_in=1209600&username=abcuser

Is there a way to work around this problem? I have to make it work with # separated query parameters. which property will contain the data after oauth-callback?

Comment: Why do you _have to_? That would go against the URI specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those aren't query parameters. They're the *fragment* of the URI - and that isn't sent to the server at all. It can only be used client-side.

From [RFC 3986](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt):

> A fragment identifier component is indicated by the presence of a number sign ("#") character and terminated by the end of the URI.

... and (emphasis mine)

> Fragment identifiers have a special role in information retrieval
>      systems as the primary form of client-side indirect referencing,
>      allowing an author to specifically identify aspects of an existing
>      resource that are only indirectly provided by the resource owner.  **As
>      such, the fragment identifier is not used in the scheme-specific
>      processing of a URI; instead, the fragment identifier is separated
>      from the rest of the URI prior to a dereference**, and thus the
>      identifying information within the fragment itself is dereferenced
>      solely by the user agent, regardless of the URI scheme.